# Multiple connections for RabbitMQ consumer

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-rabbit

I need to have my RabbitMQ consumer connect to multiple queues on different hosts. How can I have multiple connections getting messages sent to the same `onMessage` method? I tried the `@Configuration` style in [*3.5.2 Asynchronous Consumer*](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html) with 2 `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` and `ConnectionFactory` and 1 `MessageListener` but only one of them picks up messages.

Configuration code here: https://gist.github.com/mcamilleri/7212dd18d2010bf6695b (I have a similar class called `ConsumerConfiguration2` that only uses a different hostname). `MessageListener` is in a separate class.

Comment: You should have no issues having a single listener wired into two listener containers. Your Gist only has one connection factory. Turn on DEBUG logging and report back if the logs don't clear up the problem you are having.

Comment: My question wasn't clear that I have a similar class, I've now updated it.

Comment: Ok I got this working - I was using two classes when instead I should have been using one. Here's a gist with the code, not pretty but it works: https://gist.github.com/mcamilleri/bb7eacb6ea02caa1e263